# "has no method 'transition'" error with a custom transition setup on JQM 1.4.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

Up until today I had a custom page transition set up on my JQM project, like so:

```
  function myTransitionHandler(name, reverse, $to, $from)
  {
      deferred = new $.Deferred();

      //transition stuff done here

      setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve(name, reverse, $to, $from)
      }, 500)

      return deferred.promise();
  }

  $.mobile.transitionHandlers["myTransition"] = myTransitionHandler;
```

I upgraded JQM from 1.3 to 1.4 today, and now I'm getting the following error out put on the console when I change the page:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'transition'`

Having a look at the [changelog](http://jquerymobile.com/changelog/1.4.0/) for v 1.4 a particular line sticks out,

`Added transition handler object` ([93b0b48](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/93b0b48a0668e937959ab1afe16500e1dfaca7ec))

which I'm pretty sure is the the cause of this, but being a fairly inexperienced programmer I have no idea what changes I should make to my project to fit in with this. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the code I found that jQuery Mobile 1.4 default transition handlers are now defined this way:

```
$.mobile.transitionHandlers = {
    "sequential": $.mobile.SerialTransition,
    "simultaneous": $.mobile.ConcurrentTransition
};
```

Having a look at *$.mobile.SerialTransition* object definition you can find out that it is an object extending the *$.mobile.Transition* object. Here is the code taken from jQuery Mobile 1.4.

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.mobile.SerialTransition = function() {
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    $.extend($.mobile.SerialTransition.prototype, $.mobile.Transition.prototype, {
        sequential: true,

        beforeDoneOut: function() {
            if ( this.$from ) {
                this.cleanFrom();
            }
        },

        beforeStartOut: function( screenHeight, reverseClass, none ) {
            this.$from.animationComplete($.proxy(function() {
                this.doneOut( screenHeight, reverseClass, none );
            }, this ));
        }
    });

})( jQuery );
```

So, if you want to create your custom transition handler, you cannot use any more a simple function, but you must use such an object.

Also, should you want to find out more on *$.mobile.Transition* object download jQuery Mobile unminified development js and have a look at line #5903

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response. Could you possibly give me a code example? What I'm trying isn't working.

Comment: You should provide more informations about your progress. Are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, my programming skills are intermediate at best. `but you must use such an object` I do not understand where and how I would put the transition logic what object I should be using? e.e I've tried stuff like this:

      `test = new $.mobile.Transition(); `

      `$.mobile.transitionHandlers['sequential']['myTransition'] = test;`

Comment: You must not use `$.mobile.Transition()` object directly. Instead you must create a new object extending it like in the answer I posted. Also, check the assigment line (there is a wrong reference to 'sequential'). It should be: `$.mobile.transitionHandlers['myTransition'] = test;`

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help so far. This is the code I've ended up with as of now, but it's still not working - what do you think? http://pastebin.com/3Qav9gSb

Comment: No error this time. It just goes to a different page (without outputting my console.log) after which it refuses to change page again...